# How to achieve inheritance using classmethod factory functions

Tags: python, inheritance, factory-pattern

How do I use/reuse implementations in the parent class when using the [`classmethod` approach for implementing factory functions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/classmethod)?

In the example below, `class A` is fine, but `class B` is broken.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)
    @classmethod
    def from_jdata(cls, data):
        if '_id' in data:
            data['uuid'] = data['_id']
            del data['_id']
        return cls(**data)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwds)
    @classmethod
    def from_jdata(cls, data):
        # goal: make an instance of B, 
        # using the logic that is implemented in A.from_jdata
        # But does some extra stuff, akin to:
        res = A.from_jdata(B, data)
        res.__dict__['extra']='set'
        return res
```

The context is that I'm trying to instantiate instances based on JSON configuration data.  The inheritance hierarchy is deeper than just two classes, i.e. there are a number of children of `class B`.  The root of the inheritance hierarchy does some useful stuff in the factory function.  Children classes should re-use that but add on some additional operations.

Comment: I've done this in the past through registration of children and making the parent discriminate between children for deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `super`, of course:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)
    @classmethod
    def from_jdata(cls, data):
        if '_id' in data:
            data['uuid'] = data['_id']
            del data['_id']
        return cls(**data)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwds)
    @classmethod
    def from_jdata(cls, data):
        # goal: make an instance of B,
        # using the logic that is implemented in A.from_jdata
        # But does some extra stuff, akin to:
        res = super().from_jdata(data)
        # res = super(B, cls).from_jdata(data) # in python 2
        res.__dict__['extra']='set'
        return res
```

In action:

```
In [6]: b = B.from_jdata({'_id':42, 'foo':'bar'})

In [7]: vars(b)
Out[7]: {'foo': 'bar', 'uuid': 42, 'extra': 'set'}
```

Note, what you were trying to do won't work because `@classmethod` creates a descriptor that binds the class when called from either *the class or the instance*. You would have to access the raw function using something like:

```
res = A.__dict__['from_jdata'].__func__(B, data)
```

To make it work, but just use `super`, that's what it is for.

Comment: How to in python2.7 where arguments are required?

Comment: @Dave I edited in to a comment: `# res = super(B, cls).from_jdata(data) # in python 2`

Comment: it looks like `super(B, cls).from_jdata(data)` works

Comment: Why do you need to call super in init of class B? Could you not just update self.__dict__ in the init from class B itself?

Comment: @user007 you could, but it is better to re-use code instead of having to maintain the same code in two separate places

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the quick response. can you please ELI5 what is the 'same code in two separate places' here? cause I just see you needed to update self __dict__ only once. Sorry if it is obvious but I can't understand. Appreciate it.

Comment: @user007 once in `A.__init__` and once in `B.__init__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why do you need to do it in A.__init__? Does B.__init__ application alone not suffice?

Comment: @user007 this is a completely contrived example, if you want, you can entirely omit `A`, but the OP wrote `A.__init__` to do that, so presumably, there is a reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244982/discussion-between-user007-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).